# how to add two separate list to a two dimensional array?

Tags: java

I have 2 lists and I want to add the data to a 2 dimensional Array in a specific order to successfully display data in JTable. 
This is how I initialize JTable: `table = new JTable(data, columnNames);` 
The data variable is a 2 dimensional Array, columnNames are fixed and must not be considered.

I added from a Map the key an value in 2 separate Lists:

```
List<String> keyWords = new ArrayList<String>();
List<Long> valueFrequency = new ArrayList<Long>();
for (Map.Entry<String,Long> entry : counts.entrySet()) 
{
    keyWords.add(entry.getKey());
    valueFrequency.add(entry.getValue());
}
```

This works as intended!

Now the data variable should look like this (example)
`Object[][] data = {{"James", 3}, {"Hello", 2}};`. When I hardcode like this those elemens are shown as intended in the Jtable.
Now I wan to to the same dynamically by adding in the first position (in our case "James") the first element of list keyWords and for the number (in our case the number 3) the first element of list valueFrequency. Now add the second element of list keyWords in the place "Hello" and second element of list velueFrequency in the place of the number 2 and so on. Both lists are always the same size.

Can someone help me to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you provide examples of input and output? Using prosa text, I dont quite get what you try to do.

Comment: Build the array from the lists, or from the counts map ?

Comment: I have a Map already, how can i build the two dimensional array from the map?

Answer (score 1):

1. From the map

   - Using `Stream`

     ```
     Object[][] data = counts.entrySet()
                             .stream().map(e -> new Object[]{e.getKey(),e.getValue()})
                             .toArray(Object[][]::new);
     ```
   - Using `for-i` loop

     ```
     Object[][] data = new Object[counts.size()][];
     int i = 0;
     for (Map.Entry<String, Long> entry : counts.entrySet()) {
         data[i++] = new Object[]{entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()};
     }
     ```
2. From both lists :

   - Using `Stream`

     ```
     Object[][] data = IntStream.range(0, keyWords.size())
                    .mapToObj(i -> new Object[]{keyWords.get(i), valueFrequency.get(i)})
                    .toArray(Object[][]::new);
     ```
   - Using `Guava Streams`

     ```
     Object[][] data = Streams.zip(keyWords.stream(), valueFrequency.stream(), (s, l) -> new Object[]{s, l})
                              .toArray(Object[][]::new);
     ```
   - Using `for-i` loop

     ```
     Object[][] data = new Object[keyWords.size()][];
     for (int i = 0; i < keyWords.size(); i++) {
         data[i] = new Object[]{keyWords.get(i), valueFrequency.get(i)};
     }
     ```